# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, null

У меня в проекте есть TabLayout, который содержит три вкладки. 
В xml файле одного из Табов есть FloatingActionButton с присвоенным id.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorTabTwo"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:fabSize="normal" />
```

В MainActivity.java в методе onCreate нашел FAB

```
        floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
```

Создал отдельную функцию и потом вызвал её в методе onCreate

```
//Func of Floating Action Button
    public void setFloatingActionButton() {
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "Добавить",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, calculator.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

При попытке запуска на эмуляторе приложение падает и выдаёт следующее:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.valletappnew.MainActivity.setFloatingActionButton(MainActivity.java:157)
        at com.example.valletappnew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Как у вас табы сделаны? Если на фрагментах - то в `onCreate` активити они ещё могут быть не созданы, а если уже созданы и добавлены, то вашим способом до их разметки не достучаться. Если вышесказанное верно, то лучшим выходом будет управлять FAB-ом там, где он прописан - т.е. во фрагменте. Если нет - добавьте больше деталей в вопрос - пока что определённо ответить никак нельзя.

Comment: На фрагментах. До добавления FAB всё исправно работало. Подскажите, как именно я могу управлять FAB-ом там, где он прописан? В java-файле этого фрагмента, в котором находится FAB?

Comment: Да, всё верно. Во фрагменте в `onViewCreated` найдите FAB через `findViewById` и там же вешайте слушатель нажатий

Comment: Спасибо за совет!
Содержимое onCreateView
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), calculator.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
Работает!